# Publish CSPROJ without PackageReference dependencies

Tags: csproj, packagereference

If you publish a CSPROJ that has a PackageReference to i.e. the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` NuGet package, then you will also get the DLLs for `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` because the referenced package has a dependency on it. You will also get DLLs that `.Abstraction` depends on, and so on and on and on.

Is there a way to mark this PackageReference so that only its own DLLs are published and dependencies are ignored? Or in other words: How could one reference `Microsoft.Extensions.DepencyInjection` so that a publish **only** publishes `Microsoft.Extensions.DepencyInjection.dll` without any dependent DLLs?